# Can I declare Ref at the global scope to manipulate a component from a function outside its scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, scope

I would like to have a custom hook that would provide me with a `ScrollView` component and a function to imperatively control the scrolling of that given component.

I'm using a library called [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view), which allows me to catch the reference of the component trough a [prop](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view#props) called `innerRef`. Through that reference I have access to a series of [methods](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view#methods) that I can use to manipulate the scrolling.

The only way that I found for that "control function" to have access to the reference while being outside the scope of the `ScrollView` component was to create that `ref` globally using `React.createRef` like below:

```js
const ref = createRef();

const ScrollView = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      {...props}
      innerRef={(inner) => {
        ref.current = inner; //adding ref to scrollview
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );
};

const useScrollTo = () => {

  const scrollTo = (position) => {
    if (ref.current && position) {

     /* controlling scroll using ref */
      ref.current.scrollTo({
        x: 0,
        y: position,
        animate: true
      });
    }
  };

  return { ScrollView, scrollTo };
};

export default useScrollTo;
```

Even though `const` declarations at the global scope create globals that are not part of the global object it feels anti-pattern to me, so I'd like to know if there's a proper way for me to do this without the need of having a ref in the global scope like this. Is this even possible?

#### Edit

Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-archimedes-xjijjf?from-embed) of this hook being used to assist with form validation on a long form, pointing the user to the input that has failed to pass validation:

Comment: Using a global ref is not necessarily an antipattern, but it's possible that you don't need a global ref at all, and it would be enough just an upper scope ref (e.g parent ref ). What I see is that you don't need a custom hook to just return a function that has no react hooks inside and returns just a Component and the function itself.

Comment: @CesarePolonara I thought of an upper scope ref initially, but for that I'd need to have that ScrollView component nested within the hook, which would trigger many re-renders. What would you suggest for a re-usable implementation of something like this other than using a custom hook?

Comment: Could you post a complete code example of a Component where and how you are using this hook ?

Comment: @CesarePolonara I plan to use it mostly to help with form validations in long forms, positioning the viewport on the input that hasn't passed validation, I have just edited the question adding a working example applied on that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the working example you provided, this is how I would manage the scenario:
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sea-83tvx6?file=/src/ScrollView.js

The custom hook now is a real hook, since it makes use of a react hook:

```
const useScrollTo = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  const scrollTo = (position) => {
    if (ref.current && position) {
      ref.current.scrollTo({
        x: 0,
        y: position,
        animate: true
      });
    }
  };

  return {
    ref,
    scrollTo,
    ScrollView

  };
};
```

The ref is created within the hook, retrieved by your `App` Component and passed down to your `ScrollComponent`:

```
function App() {
  const { ref, scrollTo, ScrollView } = useScrollTo();
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
  const [errorPresent, setErrorPresent] = useState(false);

  const simulateValidation = () => {
    scrollTo(position);
    setErrorPresent(true);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView myRef={ref}>
    ...
    ...
```

Your `ScrollView` Component:

```
const ScrollView = ({ children, myRef, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      {...props}
      innerRef={(inner) => {
        myRef.current = inner;
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );
};
```

I did not use React.forwardRef wrapper for sake of simplicity, if you don't like the idea of having to name your refs, you can just wrap ScrollView in `React.forwardRef()` and pass the ref with `<ScrollView ref={ref}>`.

EDIT: I updated the example by returning the ScrollView Component from the hook, even though I personally don't like this practice, I understand that  some people like to use it to avoid having to import repetitive modules in their Components.